# How to use the font "c8514fix.fon" in Visual Studio Express 2012 under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, visual-studio-2012

I have the font (it comes with the OS).

There appear to be 2 problems:

1. The font is a "hidden font" that is usually only available under certain circumstances. I do not want to change system settings to 'Large fonts'.
2. I want to use the font in the text editor of Visual Studio Express 2012. I can select a font from the list of system fonts. Unfortunately often this somehow results in the usage of some 'replacement font' - no idea why. Specifically if I select 'Fixedsys' which appears to be a smaller version of c8514fix.fon then the text editor instead uses Courier or sth similar. In notepad I can select & use 'Fixedsys'.

I have tried various things without success:
Copying the file elsewhere and "installing" it results in a copy in the windows fonts directory that is just as inaccessible and "invisible" (does not show up in the font list) as the original.
Using Fontforge to create a copy with different font name etc.: Somehow Windows does not accept the copy. Preview per clicking on it shows 'Courier New' instead, installing does not appear to work either.

Comment: have you tried making a copy, changing the name, AND the file format? To like true type or something, then installing it?

Comment: @malfy Turning it into a .ttf font does not work either: Preview shows the correct name instead of the name of a replacement font but displays nothing. Generating a .ttf font out of an existing .ttf font with Fontforge does work.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel fonts are not supported since Visual Studio 2010, since it is using WPF technology to render text (which only supports real TrueType fonts).
You can't change a pixel font to a true type font by simply changing the extension.

You have to convert it with a font editor, but it's not always trivial to get it looking perfect as TrueType.

If you're lucky, someone converted the font already for you and made it available on his website. For example, there's Terminus as a "Terminal" replacement (but sadly only down to 8pt size and not 6) and Fixedsys Excelsior for a Fixedsys replacement (also only down to 8pt).